# Covariance matrix problem

Tags: regression, self-study, variance, covariance

[image]

I am having trouble figuring this out. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: block out $Q$'s rows and $\Sigma$'s columns like this:
$$
Q = \left[\begin{array}{c}
Q_1^T\\
\vdots \\
Q_n^T
\end{array}\right]
$$
and
$$
\Sigma = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\Sigma_1 & \cdots & \Sigma_n
\end{array}\right].
$$
Then 
$$
\text{tr}(Q\Sigma) = \sum_{i=1}^n Q_i^T\Sigma_i.
$$

Alternative hint 2: use properties of the trace operator (e.g. linearity and cylic property).

Alternative hint 3: Juse do out all the multiplications and use linearity/definitions. It helps to know how to write quadratic forms as a double sum, if you take this approach.